# C# Parsing RSS feed

Tags: c#, c, xml, parsing, rss

I have a problem getting a string from a element from a rss feed.

i get error here:

```
XmlNode sizeNode = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("torrent:contentLength");
```

the code runs if i leave out that line. here is rest of  it:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("movies.xml");

        var xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//rss/channel");
        var i = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in xmlNode)
        {

            XmlNode titleNode = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("title");
            XmlNode categoryNode = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("category");
            XmlNode dateNode = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate");
            XmlNode sizeNode = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("torrent:contentLength");

            if ((titleNode != null) && (dateNode != null) &&
                (categoryNode != null) && (sizeNode != null) )
            {
                DgvMain.Rows.Add();
                DgvMain.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = titleNode.InnerText;
                DgvMain.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = categoryNode.InnerText;
                DgvMain.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dateNode.InnerText;
                DgvMain.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = sizeNode.InnerText;
                i++;
            }

        }
```

here is a part from xml file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <rss version="2.0" xmlns:torrent="http://xmlns.ezrss.it/0.1/"> <channel>
> <title>movies torrents RSS feed - KickassTorrents</title>
> <link>http://kickass.to/</link>
> <description>movies torrents RSS feed</description>
> <item>
>     <title>Al Murray My Gaff My Rules 2003 Xvid Mp3.avi</title>
>
>     <category>Movies</category>
>   <author>http://kickass.to/user/Stull/</author>        <link>http://kickass.to/al-murray-my-gaff-my-rules-2003-xvid-mp3-avi-t10314315.html</link>
>     <guid>http://kickass.to/al-murray-my-gaff-my-rules-2003-xvid-mp3-avi-t10314315.html</guid>
>     <pubDate>Sat, 07 Mar 2015 00:27:56 +0000</pubDate>
>     <torrent:contentLength>548352170</torrent:contentLength>
>     <torrent:infoHash>EDBA9CB0942265440B3A0AC6FD70B39CD4384E54</torrent:infoHash>
>     <torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA[magnet:?xt=urn:btih:EDBA9CB0942265440B3A0AC6FD70B39CD4384E54&dn=al+murray+my+gaff+my+rules+2003+xvid+mp3+avi&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337]]></torrent:magnetURI>
>     <torrent:seeds>1</torrent:seeds>
>     <torrent:peers>1</torrent:peers>
>     <torrent:verified>0</torrent:verified>
>     <torrent:fileName>al.murray.my.gaff.my.rules.2003.xvid.mp3.avi.torrent</torrent:fileName>
>     <enclosure url="http://torcache.net/torrent/EDBA9CB0942265440B3A0AC6FD70B39CD4384E54.torrent?title=[kickass.to]al.murray.my.gaff.my.rules.2003.xvid.mp3.avi"
> ```
>
> length="548352170" type="application/x-bittorrent" />

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, can you post some sample XML?

Comment: There's a namespace problem (torrent), we need a sample of your xml file

Comment: i knew there was something i forgot :)..

Comment: the problem seems to be the element name "torrent:contentLength"

Comment: and i cant seem to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Since the contentLength have the prefix 'torrent:' it causes problems when trying to extract it.

I've had the same problem a couple of weeks ago.
My solution was to convert the XML schema to a class and then deserialize the XML data you fetched, into the RSS object and you would have all the properties of the XML schema.

**Step 1:** Convert schema to classes

Visual studio provides this functionality by using:
Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes

Another way to convert is using http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

**Step 2:** Deserialize using `XmlSerializer` from  System.Xml.Serialization;

**Step 3:** Access needed properties using the RSS object.

The classes will look like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "enclosure")]
public class Enclosure
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "length")]
    public string Length { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pubDate")]
    public string PubDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "contentLength", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string ContentLength { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "infoHash", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string InfoHash { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "magnetURI", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string MagnetURI { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "seeds", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string Seeds { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "peers", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string Peers { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "verified", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string Verified { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fileName", Namespace = "//kastatic.com/xmlns/0.1/")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "enclosure")]
    public Enclosure Enclosure { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "channel")]
public class Channel
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rss")]
public class KatRss
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "channel")]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "torrent", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Torrent { get; set; }
}
```

Leave out any property you don't need.